# Flash FLVPlayback CuePoint problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, action, flvplayback

I have a flash app that plays movies. It loads subtitles and subtitle times from an xml file. Now the problem is this: in one or two of the films the first subtitle disappears after only one second even though it's in and out times are correct and it should be displayed for 5 s.

I have no idea why this is happening since all the other films + subs work fine.
Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Any help is much appreciated!
m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the reason: somewhere in the xml file where the subs and times are, a time was broken due to the default line length of antiword. I'm using antiword to transform the subtitle files coming in doc format into .txt files. Since the word files are all tables, in the text file the column wasn't wide enough so the time got chopped off. Have no idea though why this affected the first sub of the film rather than the one that actually had the broken time.